# Python Recursive Generator

Tags: python, recursion, generator, yield

I'm trying to make a recursive generator, but I'm clearly missing something. Basically I have a list of positive and negative values for specific dimensions of a histogram, and want to get every combination of positive and negative.
Ex:

```
input = [[-1,2],[-3,4],[-5,6]]
```

And the result I need is (although I want this as a generator instead of a list, but you get the idea):

```
output = [[-1, -3, -5],[-1, -3, 6],[-1, 4, -5],[-1, 4, 6],[2, -3, -5],[2, -3, 6],[2, 4, -5],[2, 4, 6]]
```

I have managed to get it done, but only by appending items to a global list inside of my recursion, but I really was hoping I could just do this with a generator and iterate over my function since that would make it so much cleaner IMO.

Here's what I have now:

```
def combs(idx,array,current=[]):
    for item in array[idx]:
        current_copy = current[:]
        current_copy.append(item)
        if idx + 1 < len(array):
            combs(idx+1,array,current_copy)
        else:
            print current_copy
            # yield current_copy
```

This will print out exactly what I want, but when I try to change the print to a yield and loop over the function it doesn't work. (e.g.)

```
for item in combs(0,input,[]):
    print item
```

Comment: Please, avoid calling your variables with function names (`input` in this case) it will give you headaches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.3 or newer, you want the `yield from` statement:

```
def combs(idx,array,current=[]):
    for item in array[idx]:
        current_copy = current[:]
        current_copy.append(item)
        if idx + 1 < len(array):
            yield from combs(idx+1,array,current_copy)
        else:
            yield current_copy
```

On Python 2.7, you can expand the `yield from` into a loop:

```
def combs(idx,array,current=[]):
    for item in array[idx]:
        current_copy = current[:]
        current_copy.append(item)
        if idx + 1 < len(array):
            for i in combs(idx+1,array,current_copy):
                yield i
        else:
            yield current_copy
```

Comment: I am using 2.7, is there a similar alternative?

Comment: you should be able to loop over the recursive ``combs`` call, and yield individual values

Comment: I have tried doing exactly what I have above, except switching the print current_copy to yield current_copy, and I get no output.

Comment: So I see that it works, but I'm confused as to why I need to loop over the recursive function call, can you explain that a little bit?

Comment: Calling ``combs`` just gives you a generator object, you have to loop over it to get the values out of it. It's not like calling a regular function that returns a value. ``yield from`` is just syntactic sugar for consuming an iterable (like a generator) and yielding the values.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for this task is the `itertools.product` function:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> input = [[-1,2],[-3,4],[-5,6]]
>>> list(product(*input))
[(-1, -3, -5), (-1, -3, 6), (-1, 4, -5), (-1, 4, 6), (2, -3, -5), (2, -3, 6), (2, 4, -5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

Comment: This is great and solves the overall problem at hand! I still am curious as to why what I was trying to do isn't working though :(

Comment: If he wants the generator should do `myGenerator = product(*myInput)`.

Comment: @Mr.E Correct, I used `list()` to demonstrate the result.