# Python recursive generator breaks when using list() and append() keywords

Tags: python, list, recursion, generator, coroutine

I have only recently learned about coroutines using generators and tried to implement the concept in the following recursive function:

```
def _recursive_nWay_generator(input: list, output={}):
    '''
    Helper function; used to generate parameter-value pairs
    to submit to the model for the simulation.

    Parameters
    ----------
    input : list of tuple
        every tuple of the list must be of the form:
        ``('name_of_parameter', iterable_of_values)``

    output : list, optional
        parameter used for recursion; allows for list building
        across subgenerators

    Returns
    -------
    Generator :
        Specifications used for simulation setup of the form:
        ``{'par1': val1, ...}``
    '''
    # exit condition
    if len(input) == 0:
        yield output
    # recursive loop
    else:
        curr = input[0]
        par_name = curr[0]
        for par_value in curr[1]:
            output[par_name] = par_value
            # coroutines for the win!
            yield from _recursive_nWay_generator(input[1:], output=output)
```

Function somewhat works as intended:

```
testlist = [('a', (1, 2, 3)), ('b', (4, 5, 6)), ('c', (7, 8))]
for a in _recursive_nWay_generator(testlist):
    print(a)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 7}
{'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 8}
{'a': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 7}
{'a': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 8}
{'a': 1, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}
{'a': 1, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}
{'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 7}
{'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 8}
{'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 7}
{'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 8}
{'a': 2, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}
{'a': 2, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}
{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 7}
{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 8}
{'a': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 7}
{'a': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 8}
{'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}
{'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}
```

However, it breaks when I try to append to an existing list or construct a new one:

```
gen = _recursive_nWay_generator(testlist)
print(list(gen))
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}]
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35015181/python-recursive-generator) was attempting to do something close to what I have, but I'm not seeing answers that could help.

I am honestly clueless as to how to solve this, the online searches I tried gave nothing no matter how I phrase the question. If this was answered before I'll be happy to just follow the link.

Comment: @j1-lee is not correct, actually. The problem is not the mutable default itself but that the algorithm reuses `output` in the recursive call.

Comment: You are reusing the same dict and mutating it each time. Consider `g = _recursive_nWay_generator(testlist)` then `next(g) is next(g)` =>  `True`. When you print them one at a time, you don't realize it's the same dictionary being mutated every time. But when you see them all in a list it's clear.

Comment: Ok, based on comments so far it looks like the problem is with the fact that I am trying to modify the same mutable object in the recursion, which was my intention. Are @j1-lee and Mark implying that the list population happens only after the generator is exhausted?

Comment: No, that's not what happens - the issue is that when you print the results during the loop you're printing the state that the dict had _at that point of the iteration_. Subsequent iterations modify the object (if you hold a reference on the initial object yielded, and print it at each step, you'll see it mutating too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is reusing the same mutable `output` dict during the iteration and recursive calls. That is, you `yield output` and then later on you modify it with `output[par_name] = par_value` but it's the same dict in each case - so you're modifying the instance which was already returned! If you append each result into a list and then print them all at the end, you'll see that they're identical - it's the same result yielded each time.

The simplest way to "fix" your existing code is to yield copies, i.e. change the line:

```
yield output
```

into this:

```
yield dict(output.items())
```

However, this algorithm is not great, and I recommend you look for something better. Using recursion is poor choice here. I'll offer you a simple/direct way to generate the sequence more efficiently:

```
import itertools as it 

testlist = [('a', (1, 2, 3)), ('b', (4, 5, 6)), ('c', (7, 8))]
keys, vals = zip(*testlist)
for p in it.product(*vals):
    print(dict(zip(keys, p)))
```

Comment: Thanks so much worked like a charm! And yeah I would use itertools if this was actual production code XD 
I tried making a copy with the `copy.deepcopy()` before posting the question right above the yield but that did not work probably for the same reason; nevertheless, thanks for the answer!